# Soomla store, not getting any market items on Android and not allowing purchases

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, soomla

I recently upgraded to the latest version of the Soomla Store - 1.11.3 from 1.11.1. However, within the editor, in the Soomla settings it tells me there is a new version available. When I click it, it installs 1.11.1 again. Not sure what's going on with that.

In any case... OnMarketItemsRefreshFinished is returning an empty list. I did make changes to the items I have in the Android play store and double checked to make sure they're all active.

OnUnexpectedStoreError isn't being called so there is no error from what I can tell. 
I also ran adb logcat on the device and still don't see anything that looks like it could cause it to not work.

In addition, if I try and purchase an item I get the Authentication is required message.
I checked that I'm logging into the play store on the device and can even see my order history. I also confirmed that I have my email address setup as a tester in the developer console in the play store.

Everything seems to be configured fine.
I tried increasing the Store version # but there was no change.
I have Debug Native and Debug Unity both checked along with Test Purchases under Google Play.

iOS seems to be working fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I still haven't been able to find out anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it working. First I removed all of Soomla and reinstalled the latest from the asset store. I did **not** click on the newer version message in the Soomla settings.
Next, I did a complete build and installed it on an Android device and checked a purchase again. I once again got the same Authentication message.
Next I checked the log to see if there were any errors and there wasn't other than the Purchase 2 error for the authentication.
Finally I uploaded this build as an alpha build and once approved, I downloaded it from the play store using the opt in link for the alpha testing group.
Now I tried a purchase and everything works fine.